# Zen Barcode Generator generating wrong code128

Tags: c#, barcode

I need help with `ZenBarcodeGenerator.dll`

The generator works fine but when it's a number between characters is not generating a correct barcode. Example:

[image]

My reader will read this as:

```
15s±s±a
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thank's in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and add to the question :)